# What's the point of CORS if apps need it to allow any origin?

Tags: c#, .net, mobile, cors

I don't mean for this to be a negative question, but i'm building a mobile application and a web server to host content for the mobile app, and I'm trying to implement responsible security.

While developing, i ran into the infamous CORS issue.

Based on all the information I can find on CORS and mobile applications, it seems the only thing to do is to set **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** to *.

So if that's the case, what's the point of the CORS setting?
It means anyone from any server/domain can attempt to make requests against my server?

My server api will require authentication and a specific client header value, but I feel like the CORS setting is pointless in this case, but at the same time, without setting it, my app won't be able to communicate with my server.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

CORS is designed to stop people from making requests on the behalf of others in a browser context.

Like if you log on to Site A which then sets an auth cookie in your browser and then when you visit malicious Site B could make that same request to Site A. The browser would happily pass along your cookies for Site A with the request and but the response would be to a script on Site B.

A good CORS-setting here would be something like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://site-a.com` which would stop Site B from tricking your browser to make the request. A lot of sites ignore this though and just set it to * which basically makes this worthless.

It is just for browsers though, I can always just make a plain request using CURL or any other tool to you endpoint which just ignores CORS.

You can read more about this over at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (and you should since it is a really important subject that a lot of people get wrong).

As for your mobile app I don't think setting it to * would be a problem unless you are consuming the same API from a browser based site (which would then make it vunerable).

Comment: I understand the intended benefits of CORS, that's why I asked in the case of mobile applications. Why would it change anything if I consume the same API from a browser or not?
How does that make it any more or less secure?

Comment: If you consume the same API from a browser then allowing all origins for the API could open it up for XSS attacks (as I described above). It still wouldn't affect your app though since it wouldn't share its cookies and other stuff with the browser.

Comment: I have a question here, so I allowed only my site (react app) in Allowed origins, but still I am getting the CORS blocked issue when I open that website from mobile. How can I solve this?

Comment: That is a new question and not something to be answered in a comment. You need to include way more information then what could fit here.